# Set Width of Fragment as a percentage of screen Width

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a `Fragment` I need to span from the bottom to the top of the screen, and from the left edge to 80% of the screen.

I've tried Using `android:layout_weight="0.8"` I get an 'Invalid layout parameter' message, even when I nest the `<fragment>` in another `<RelativeLayout>` or `<LinearLayout>`

Right now, the height spans from top to bottom, because of `android:layout_height="fill_parent"`
But width is still set to `wrap_content` because I have no idea how to set is to 80% of screen width.

```
<fragment
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/xFragment"
        android:name="com.example.x.x.xFragment"/>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put your fragment in a linear layout, something like this:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" 
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:weightSum="10">

    <fragment
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="8"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/xFragment"
            android:name="com.example.x.x.xFragment"/>


     <View
            android:id="@+id/otherElement"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Hope it helps you!!

Comment: If the answer is usseful for you, Could you mark upvote??@KNS

Answer (score 2):

Fragments do not have parameters like height, width ,margins. View and ViewGroup have parameters like height, width ,margins. So, you adjust the container into which you are placing the fragment.